# How to pass int array into Android OpenGl fragment shader

Tags: android, opengl-es, shader

I am very new to OpenGl and shaders in general. I want to use a static int array from my java code in the fragment shader to manipulate the color of the camera. Is there a way to pass in my int array to the shader or just have the shader be able to access my array somehow?

Thanks, 
Mike

Comment: Hi @MikeShiny have u found the solution, I tried the second solution and it looks like it works with arrays with small sizes, but when it comes to stuff like 512*512 arrays it will give "Too many uniforms" is that correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct way to use a so called static array within your shader code is to pass it as an Uniform:

http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glUniform

Within your shader code you specify you need an external array:

```
uniform int colors[3]; // Specify an array of 3 integers
```

within your java code use this:

```
int array[3] = {0, 1, 2};
int location = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program_id, "colors");
GLES20.glUniform1iv(location,
              3,
              array,
              0);
```

Comment: How do I find out what the maximum size I can use for the array is? Thanks

Comment: @Trax I have tried to use the overload function of it that works with a float buffer but it does not work, this one works, is it possible to use the one with float(maybe I am using it wrong)
GLES20.glUniform1fv(maskLoc, fb.remaining(), fb)
nice ans anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

Since you are trying to manipulate the color of the camera, I assume you are trying to pass a small array into the fragment shader (probably 3 or 4 integers).

Because there's probably only one camera with the same color for all the fragments, the easiest way to pass the data is using an **uniform**. In your fragment declare an uniform:

```
uniform vec4 cameraColor;
```

and then in your Java code, get the location of the uniform and pass the data to it (this is C++ code, Java code might be a bit different):

```
GLint uniColorLocation = glGetUniformLocation( shaderProgram, "cameraColor" );
glUniform4i( uniColorLocation, array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3] );
```

If you'd like to pass many colors into a fragment shader, you cold use the fragment **attributes** (ins) to pass the data. In Java code you would use calls such as `glVertexAttribPointer` and `glBufferData` to achieve this. Another option is to use **texture data** to pass information to the shaders. Here, a single texel could correspond to one object's camera color.

Comment: Thanks for the examples. It is actually a very large array (about 516*516) but this will help!